# How to run a jsfiddle result with url?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I have this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/vdk7guob/

```
<div id='container'>
Hello World
</div>
```

I'd like to run it so that when I go to a url it'll just show me the results window (NOT the editor). So I'd just see a blank "Hello World" on the screen. It'd be nice if jsfiddle had a query string to do this as an option: https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/vdk7guob/?run=true or something.

Is this possible with jsfiddle, or some other workaround?

p.s I'm trying to test some things with mobile that's why I'd like a url to my running fiddle (not editor).

Comment: *"I'm trying to test some things with mobile that's why I'd like a url to my running fiddle (not editor)"* I'd just set up a simple web server on my local machine and use the PC's IP address to access it from my mobile device.

Comment: jsve, can't. I need this to be around whenever I leave my house (and take my laptop with me) as well. this is for demo purposes. I mean, currently I'm doing it like that for development. but I need somewhere to host for demo purposes. jsfiddle's one step away from that.

Comment: Means you want api response from jsfiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle once had this option, it was the "mobile" icon for those who remember..

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Add `/show` to the end of your URL: https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/vdk7guob/show

Comment: While this works for the OP's scenario, I would like to point out that this still applies the `<iframe>` around the result. Might be a show-stopper for some cases.

Comment: Link does not work. The op wants the output to open in a separate window or tab. Maybe it used to work?

Comment: Link now redirects to the original view.

Answer (score 6):

If this is only for demo purpose, then you should be satisfied with this: https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/vdk7guob/embedded/result/

as with pattern:

```
url: https://jsfiddle.net/_USER_/_FIDDLEID_/embedded/result/
```

Comment: While this works for the OP's scenario, I would like to point out that this still applies the `<iframe>` around the result. Might be a show-stopper for some cases

Comment: Sometime recently, jsfiddle started redirecting `/embedded/result/` on mobile to the code editor. So use the `/show` solution instead if you just want to link people to the rendered jsfiddle result as that's what it's for.

Comment: This is now redirecting straight to the full editor on desktop as well. Sigh, it was probably used for spam or phishing or whatever :( hmph